# ASP.NET MVC, как открыть word файл, внести изменения и отдать его на скачивание

Tags: c#

Целый день провозился с *Openxml SDK*.
Задача такая: нужно открыть файл (шаблон документа, который в doc формате), в нем поменять 2-3 строчки, вставить изображение (вместо одного ключевого слова) и отдать на скачивание.
Поделитесь, пожалуйста, вариантами реализации - буду очень благодарен.

Comment: может стоит воспользоваться стандатрной либой от майкрософта, которая ставится с офисом?

Comment: к сожалению нет, это Web приложение, на сервере нет установленного офиса.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Office.interop.Word  В самом шаблоне отмечаете нужные места ###табличка### , ###картинка### , а потом методом поиска и замены меняете всё что нужно. Готов предложить пример по работе с экселем, он для этих целей подходит лучше )

Comment: interop не подойдет, т.к. на сервере нет установленного Офиса, а без него работать не будет

Comment: Не в коем случае не используйте для этих целей Office.Interop https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757. Очень часто он порождает утечки памяти, а также работает очень медленно.

Comment: вот пожтому и хочу OpenXML SDK для этих целей использовать

Comment: @Fullbalanced А можете рассказать в чём тут суть вопроса? Примеров редактирования docx через OpenXML SDK много. Поменяли файл, затем отдать полученный файл методом контоллера `File`.

Comment: так в том то и дело, примеров крайне мало, я англоязычную часть всю прошерстил. Более менее вменяемых примеров нет. Последнее с чем столкнулся, ок, текст менять научился, с помощью regexp (на MSDN есть примеры), но если текст форматированный - не помагает. Пока что нашел решение в виде DocX библиотеки, но это не лучший вариант. Поэтому очень прошу, если есть примеры, буду очень очень вам благодарен )